# Is there a way to poll totalSupply of an ERC20 token on a specific Block?

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, python

I am using web3.py, and i am trying to get block-specific data of some ERC20 token contracts.
Also, i tried with Google's BigQuery, but both seem to give the totalSupply at the 'latest' block.

Is there any way to get the contract data/storage at a specific block?
Or i need to calculate the changes of the totalSupply by running back on each mint from the current value, or running forward from the token's initial deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [specify the block](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.call) to get the data from when calling or transacting using `web3.py`.
here is an example :

```
token_contract.functions.myBalance().call(block_identifier=10)
```

If you can get the total supply from the contract(which i think u can) then this is your solution

Comment: Awesome! it got me exactly what i needed, Thanks!